# Blaze: For finding and flagging low-quality posts

Tags: app, website

[image: blaze answer list]

### About

Simple webapp to check the API for new content (answers / questions), and display it in a scannable format. `flag` button posts to Charcoal HQ, can be expanded to other rooms.

#### License

MIT License.

#### Site

http://erwaysoftware.com/blaze

#### Platform

Ideally everything, in practice probably less. Except IE, of course. No guarantees there.

### Contact

Ping us in [Charcoal HQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) if you have suggestions!

### Code

Source is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/blaze).

Comment: What is "Site API Name"? A little help please.

Comment: @ADTC Eventually we're going to document that. Basically it's the "short name" of the site - think `stackoverflow`, `superuser`, `softwarerecs`, `beer`, `space`, `russian`, etc.

Comment: I don't see any **flag** links. Also the site doesn't play well with Firefox on Galaxy S3 (mobile browser). Looks like a desktop site that needs zooming out.

Comment: @ADTC We might try to make it mobile-friendly for smallish devices in the future (works fine on my iPad), but it's not very high on my list of things to do. It's not a production-level app yet, TBH this post is here mostly because it's needed to get write access through the API. But as for the flag links - you have to click the "Authenticate" button at the top.

Comment: @CareBear You don't need the post the register, but you do need it to get write access. We've been running for quite a while without a post, but I wanted to add write stuff to it.

Comment: Alright. What is your target user base? And what limitation(s) of the current flagging system are you addressing with this web app? *Expand your 'question' post with the response.*

Comment: Thank you: the 'view all recent comments' feature might be [helpful for moderators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276254/139866).

Comment: A question or request: no matter what type of data it's retrieving, it's always the same URL e.g. http://erwaysoftware.com/blaze/#site=buddhism ... could you encode the data type in the URL (to make it RESTful and easy to bookmark) e.g. like http://erwaysoftware.com/blaze/#site=buddhism/comments or http://erwaysoftware.com/blaze/#site=buddhism?get=comments

Comment: @ChrisW Not a bad idea; I might try to implement that. If you'd like to take a shot at it, PRs are always appreciated :)

Comment: It seems to be enough to add the following to the end of script.js - `if (site) {
        var wanted = lochash.substr(lochash.indexOf('wanted=')).split('&')[0].split('=')[1];
        if (wanted) {
            apiEndpoint = wanted;
            RefreshData();
        }
    }` - that lets you add something like `&wanted=comments` to the URL.